# Realm for react-native gives IOS version warning

Tags: ios, react-native, realm

After installing the latest version of Realm using npm, when I tried to run my react-native app, I got the following warning:

> libRealmReact.a(GCDWebServers_vers.o)) was built for newer iOS version
>   (8.0) than being linked (7.0)

The build failed with the following error:

> ld: targeted OS version does not support use of thread local variables
>   in __ZN5realm4util13get_thread_idEv for architecture x86_64 clang:
>   error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

The react-native docs don't have any info on how to change the target from iOS 7 to iOS 8.

Is there a way to get the version of Realm that works with iOS 7?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug which was fixed by https://github.com/realm/realm-js/pull/506.